# Find by list or field together by Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

There is some class which contains `userEntityList` and field "author" type of `UserEntity`. I use hibernate and Spring Data. When I write method `findAllByUserEntityList(UserEntity user)` or method `findAllByAuthor(UserEntity user)` it works properly, but doesn't work if I try do this: `findAllByUserEntityListOrAuthor(UserEntity user)`. I must find all entity by `UserEntity` which contain in this list or if it is equals to author. How I can do it?

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    private UserEntity author;

    private List<UserEntity> userEntityList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this option

```
@Query("FROM SomeEntity where author = :user or :user in elements(userEntityList)")
List<Product> findAllByUserEntityListOrAuthor(@Param("user") UserEntity user);
```